# Why can't I get vue transition-group working?

Tags: vue.js

I've created a code sandbox for a tab component. The transition-group does not work and I can't figure out why.  Here's the link to the code sandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/vue3-tab-component-tailwind-useyrr

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the `v-for` elements are added to DOM on mount. They basically transition while their contents are being hidden.

I don't know why you expect the `v-show` elements to transition, because you haven't added a transition at that level.

In my estimation, you don't need a `v-for`. All you need is a `<transition>` around a `div` showing the active tab content.

See it [working](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue3-tab-component-tailwind-forked-43zwwf?file=/src/components/Tabs.vue).

Notes:

- I've slightly refactored making a tab active (by using the tab index)
- I fixed the transition classes (note this [breaking change](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/transition.html) in the v3 migration guide)
- note the `appear` and `mode="out-in"` attributes on the `<transition>`
- probably the most important is the `:key` attribute on the inner div of the `<transition>`. It makes the element get replaced when `activeTabIndex` changes. Without that `:key`, Vue would reuse the same DOM element and we wouldn't see a transition, except the entering one, when mounting the parent component.

Comment: Thank you tao!.  I like the active tab changes and your explanations are great. I full understand what you've done / explained.